# Converting hh:mm:ss.ffffff to HH:mm tt

Tags: mysql, sql

I want a way to insert time as `HH:mm tt` rather than `hh:mm:ss.ffffff`.

I know this is done through using sql query, any help with that?
Also, Why is phpmyadmin showing milliseconds? Should I change something from the settings? I don't really need milliseconds...

Comment: You want to store it as an actual date type not a string. You can convert it when you pull the data out.

Comment: Store it as a datatype that is appropriate for storing dates! You'll most likely save yourself a lot of headaches in the future, due to low performance, high query times, high resource usage (CPU, RAM / disk IO), just to name a few.

Comment: `DATETIME` does not have a format.  What you're seeing is just how it's being rendered.  You should never store `DATETIME` values as anything other than a `DATETIME`.  You can configure the way it is displayed at your presentation layer, or from the query.  But you should *never* store it as a different datatype.

Comment: I'm using "time" as datatype, I don't need date neither..